# Python returning function value to another value

Tags: python, function

I'm having an issue with some of my code in Python.
I realise that it is quite a lazy effort but I have been trying to figure out how to return function values for 3 hours now.

This is just an extract of some of the code and functions:

```
def main():
    another_round = 'y'
    print (''' 
    Hawaiian Beach Bike Hire
    ''')
    while another_round == 'y':
       biketype = bikeType()
       bikeDays(biketype)
       bikeDistance(biketype)
       print ('''

    days bike rent ($):''',bikeDays(biketype))
       print ('extra distance rent ($): ',bikeDistance(biketype))
       print ('''

    total amount ($):''',bikeDistance(biketype) + bikeDays(biketype))
       another_round= input('''
    is there anymore bikes to count?''')

def bikeType():
    biketype = input ('Bike type ')
    if biketype == 'Kids'or biketype == 'kids':
        biketype = 15
    elif biketype == 'womans'or biketype == 'Womans':
        biketype = 20
    elif biketype == 'Mens'or biketype == 'mens':
        biketype = 25
    else:
        print ('choose a valid bike')
    return biketype

    def bikeDistance(biketype):
    if biketype == 15:
        biked= 1.5
    elif biketype == 20:
        biked= 2.0
    elif biketype == 25:
        biked= 2.2
    distanceRent = float(input('Distance Traveled '))
    bikeAdd = distanceRent * biked
    return biketype



main()
```

It doesn't seem right that I'm using `biketype` to return most functions, but anything else does not work.

This program **functions correctly** (i.e the whole program together produces the right calculations as is) BUT, everytime a function is called in the main and `biketype` is used, it repeats asking for input for those sections (distance traveled etc)

Is there a way to only return the values and not the string?

Comment: Could you write as small a program as possible which still has the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
def main():
    another_round = 'y'
    print ("Hawaiian Beach Bike Hire")
    while another_round == 'y':
       biketype = bikeType()
       bikedays = bikeDays(biketype)
       bikedistance = bikeDistance(biketype)

       print ("days bike rent ($): {}".format(bikedays))
       print ("extra distance rent ($): {}".format(bikedistance))
       print ("total amount ($): {}".format(bikedistance + bikedays))
       another_round = input("is there anymore bikes to count?")
```

The problem was you were calling `bikeDays()` and `bikeDistance()` inside the print functions as well as after you declared `biketype`. I also just put the `print()`s on a single line for clarity.